# Xcode dependencies build folders for different schemas

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, build

My project depends on several sub-projects (static libraries) which configured properly and put their .h file in place (using *Copy public headers* build phase). All of sub-projects have two configurations: Debug and Release. 
In my main project I have several configurations. When I chose configuration that differs from Debug or Release, the project fails to build as it can't find my dependencies. And I know why - for all the dependencies, Release configuration was invoked and all the dependencies' products were places in the *Release-iphoneos* folder, whereas main project by default is seeking for dependencies in its' `$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)` folder which eventually resolves into `<Target Name>-iphoneos`. The question here - is how should I force Xcode to place dependencies' products into the correct build folder, dictated by the main project (i.e. `<Target Name>-iphoneos`)?